# Simulate absolute web paths on PC

Tags: html, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I am working with a web site that uses absolute paths to files but does not specify a domain.  A link to `/public_html/images/image1.jpg` is coded as `"/images/image1.jpg"`, a link to the home page is coded simply as `"/"`.  This is done so that the site can be deployed and maintained on multiple domains.

The problem I'm having is with testing the HTML files by opening them on a PC.  Because the base location is coded as `"/"`, the browser assumes all the files and directories are in the root of the C drive.

Is there a way to simulate the site on a Windows PC so that all images and CSS are loaded correctly?  I thought about creating a new partition and putting everything in the root of that partition but wanted to know if there was an easier way.

Comment: did you try changing / to ./

(. means present directory)

Comment: We're trying to stick with absolute paths though.

Comment: do you want to define environment specific urls or the initial path of urls?

Comment: I want links to images and other files to be the same throughout the site code, regardless of how deep in the directory structure they are.  So when `/images/image1.jpg` is linked from `/directory1/`, `/directory1/directory2/`, and `/directory1/directory2/directory3/`, I want the link to that image to be the same.

Comment: what about
{images folder at local}/someimagefolder/images1/image1.jpg
,
{images folder at testing server}/someimagefolder/images1/image1.jpg
,
{images folder at live}/someimagefolder/images1/image1.jpg

Comment: Use a web server to serve the files? You have a myriad of options. Perhaps the best would be a Vagrant box that has the same web server as the production environment. What technology is the site served with in production?

Comment: @steveax I think the problem OP is facing is on dev boxes, where web server is not accessible.

Comment: The issue is not that the web server is not accessible, but that I'm using a Windows tool (Notepad++) to write the site, so it has to stay on my PC while I'm working on it.

Comment: @MohitKanwar the dev environment should ideally be identical (or at least as close as possible) to the production environment. This is a trivial thing these days with virtualization.

Comment: @steveax Ideally yes. But somehow that is not the condition in this particular case.